# QMenu exec to return on a QMenu click (instead of QAction)

Tags: qt, qt4, qmenu, qaction

I am building a menu and I would like to be able to click both on `QAction` and `QMenu` items.

When running `exec`, nothing happens if I click on a `QMenu`.
Even if I added an action to the `QMenu`.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is what I tried:

```
QMenu* menu = new QMenu( "xxx", topMenu );
QAction* action = menu->menuAction();
topMenu->addAction( action );
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

I do not know why `exec()` makes it different, but to walk-around it you can create subclass of `QMenu` to be your topMenu so that it handles mouse release event manually like this:

```
void CustomMenu::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {

    QAction *const actionAtEvent = actionAt(event->pos());

    if (actionAtEvent)
        actionAtEvent->trigger();

    QMenu::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

**Original, not helpfull answer:**

It might help you to use [QMenu::menuAction()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmenu.html#menuAction) to get associated `QAction` and connect it's signals.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already used menuAction (see updated post), but how can I connect the signal to be used while running exec?

Comment: I gave it a try without success. The method is being called while the menu is executed, but exec method doesn't return until a proper QAction is clicked.

Comment: Maybe I do not quite follow what are you trying achieve. I created menu topMenu. It has childMenu, with some actions. I exec() topMenu, popup shows, click on childMenu item to expand it (clock NOT on it's child actions), this method gets called, and childMenu->menuAction() action gets triggered, signal/slot called, menu closes. 
And you wanted to..?

Comment: Well that's exactly what I am trying to do...I have exactly the same you described except that the menu doesn't close itself.

Comment: The thing is that I am using an action at the level of the menu itself (by using menu->featureAction() )